# modular arithmetic help

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

1. $3t_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$
2. $t_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$

how can we derive line 2 from line 1?

Comment: Multiply by $2
$.

Comment: sorry didn't get your answer the first time :)

Comment: No problem. It was likely overly terse.

Comment: The answer is **closed as off topic**...so I can't answer it...so I am posting this comment.....Observe that- $$3t_1\equiv1\pmod5\implies3t_1\equiv6\pmod5$$(Since $6$ divided by $5$ gives $1$ as remainder).....Now,dividing both sides of the congruence by $3$,we get,$$t_1\equiv2\pmod5$$....(Note that we could only write this as $\gcd(3,5)=1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $5$ is prime, we know that the modular multiplicative inverse exists for the co-prime equivalence classes; that is $\forall a:\gcd(a, 5)=1, \exists b: ab\equiv 1 \bmod 5 $

So $a^{-1}$ means something and is unique to equivalence. In particular, $3^{-1} \equiv 2 \bmod 5 $ because $3\times 2 =6 \equiv 1 \bmod 5$.

From line 1, all calculated $\bmod 5$: 
$$\begin{align}
2\times 3t_1 &\equiv 2\times 1  \\
\implies 6t_1&\equiv 2 \\
\implies 5t_1 + t_1 &\equiv 2 \\
\implies t_1 &\equiv 2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the inverse of $3$ modulo $5$. The general way to have the inverse is from a *Bézout's relation* between the number and the modulus, from the *extended Euclidean algorthm*, but here it is obvious:
$$2\cdot 3 -5=1, \quad\text{whence}\quad3^{-1}=2\mod 5.$$

Answer (score 0):

$3t_1 = 5k + 1 = 6k + (1-k) \implies 3 \mid (1-k) \implies 1-k = 3m \implies k = 1- 3m\implies t_1 = \dfrac{6k+(1-k)}{3}= 2k+ \dfrac{1-k}{3} = 2k+m = 2(1-3m) + m = -5m+2 = 2\pmod 5$ as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

$$3t_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 5\iff3t_1=1+5m\iff 6t_1=5t_1+t_1=2+5(2m)$$ Hence $$t_1\equiv 2\pmod 5 $$